# counting elements in data frame and creating new colums

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame of non-numeric data, i.e.,

```
Col1 <- c("a", "b","b",NA)
Col2 <- c(NA, "a", "c", NA)
Col3 <- c(NA,NA,"b", "a")

dat <- data.frame(Col1, Col2, Col3)
dat
# Col1 Col2 Col3
#  1    a <NA> <NA>
#  2    b    a <NA>
#  3    b    c    b
#  4 <NA> <NA>    a
```

I want to add columns that count the occurrences of each character in each row. I want the data frame to look like this

```
dat
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 a b c
# 1    a <NA> <NA> 1 0 0
# 2    b    a <NA> 1 1 0
# 3    b    c    b 0 2 1
# 4 <NA> <NA>    a 1 0 0
```

I used the function

```
f <- function(x) {
 sum(x == "a", na.rm = T)}
```

to find column "a","b", and "c",  but there are many characters to account for and I was hoping someone could suggest a faster way. I suspect the `apply` function could be used, but I have not had any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may count each factor level using `table`. This function is applied to each row using `apply`. Use `factor` and its `levels` argument to count also (possible) factor levels not represented in a row. In the first step we find all possible values which the data can take.

```
levs <- unique(unlist(dat))
count <- t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = levs))))
cbind(dat, count)

#   Col1 Col2 Col3 a b c
# 1    a <NA> <NA> 1 0 0
# 2    b    a <NA> 1 1 0
# 3    b    c    b 0 2 1
# 4 <NA> <NA>    a 1 0 0
```

Comment: I'm sure you can make this much better. You're calling `table` *and* `factor` for every row in the dataset! That seems inefficient.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks a lot for your comment. I entirely agree - I wasn't very happy with it. But this was what came to my mind and instead of throwing it away I decided to shared it...;)

Answer (score 1):

```
# your data
Col1<-c("a", "b","b",NA)
Col2<-c(NA, "a", "c", NA)
Col3<-c(NA,NA,"b", "a")

# the data frame. note you don't want the c() function, as you had above
dat<-data.frame(Col1,Col2,Col3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Solution:

```
# a vector of all the values we are searching for (less NAs)
unq_values <- unique(unlist(dat))
unq_values <- unq_values[!is.na(unq_values)]

# function: for a given unique value, count matches by row
freq_vec <- function(u) apply(dat, 1, function(x) sum(grepl(u, x)))

# now sapply() that function, and bind to your original data.frame
cbind(dat, sapply(unq_values, freq_vec))
```

That produces the result you want:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 a b c
1    a <NA> <NA> 1 0 0
2    b    a <NA> 1 1 0
3    b    c    b 0 2 1
4 <NA> <NA>    a 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably suggest something like this:

```
cbind(dat, 
      apply(table(cbind(rn = 1:nrow(dat), 
                        stack(lapply(dat, as.character)))), 
            c(1, 2), sum))
```

It's reasonably fast. [Here's a Gist with the functions I ran](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/9464e97957e843f3eb91). And here are the results.

`fun1` is this answer, `fun2` is Henrik's, `fun3` is akrun's, and `fun4` is arvi1000's.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(reshape2)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), fun4())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#  fun1() 1.882373 1.981502 2.031227 2.074144  4.193716   100
#  fun2() 2.201289 2.271821 2.316432 2.346138  5.147774   100
#  fun3() 6.565937 6.821392 6.928942 7.078843 11.700034   100
#  fun4() 2.043613 2.120811 2.151803 2.206342  5.283656   100
```

Of course, benchmarking on four rows of data doesn't give a good picture of things, so I scaled it up a little bit and tested again:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, replicate(5000, dat, FALSE))
dim(dat)
# [1] 20000     3
system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.657   0.004   0.662 
system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   7.730   0.029   7.787 
system.time(fun3())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  16.795   0.063  16.887 
system.time(fun4())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.128   0.011   2.141
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also:

```
library(reshape2)    
cbind(dat,aggregate(value~Var2, melt(t(dat)), FUN=table)[,-1])
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 a b c
#1    a <NA> <NA> 1 0 0
#2    b    a <NA> 1 1 0
#3    b    c    b 0 2 1
#4 <NA> <NA>    a 1 0 0
```